# Switching from one language to another says (Access Denied) using D8's multilingual module

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I working on D8's multilingual website and using the domains as the language detection for instance: es.example.com

My issue is that whenever i am logged in from English site, and then switching to another (for example Spanish site) it says that am not logged in (Access Denied), i want it to be logged in for the rest of the languages once i logged in from English site.

Anyone knows the solution?

Thanks in advance.